# Dynamic Creation of JSON Object Arrays

Tags: java, json, dynamic

This is a continuation of my work on a gradebook program.  I have been posting my questions related to JSON and connecting two applications to StackOverflow because I've been having a really difficult time with that part.

I have been attempting to create an HTTP POST request that uses JSON for the purpose of sending information from a Java gradebook application to a Rails web-based application that displays those grades in the form of a report to students.

Ultimately, I want to send more than just one student's information. Furthermore, each student might have anywhere from 0 to 50 assignments, descriptions of the assignments, as well as grades for those assignments. On top of that there will be multiple classes/courses of students. All this information needs to be "read in" to the JSON object. Does anyone have any suggestions about how I could modify this code so that I could send all that data? 
The farthest that I was able to take the JSON-related part of code is shown below.  However, that code needs to be modified as the following questions suggest.
1.   How do I create the array of JSON objects dynamically rather than how it is shown below (since the courses, students, and grades will vary and be read in from the Java program)?
2.  How do I synthesize/combine the three JSON arrays of objects below to make it work?  My idea is that I write the array of course objects then somehow embed  the array of student objects as part of each course object, then somehow embed the array of grade objects as part of each student object.

```
 {‘JSONArrayOfCourseObjects’ : [{‘courseID’ : ‘Botany101FallSemester’, ‘courseInstructor’ : 
  ‘Mr.  Smith’}, {‘courseID’ : ‘Physics101FallSemester’, ‘courseInstructor’ : ‘Mrs. Newton}, 
   etc.]}

 {‘JSONArrayOfStudentObjects’ : [{‘Name’ : ‘John Doe’, ‘StudentID’ : ‘12345678’, ‘Address’ :
  ‘1234 Main Street’}, {‘Name’ : ‘Don Corleone’, ‘StudentID’ : ‘87654321’, ‘Address’ : 
  ‘121 Walberry Ave’}, etc.]}

 {‘JSONArrayOfGradeObjects’ : [{‘nameOfAssignment’ : ‘Irrigation Homework 1’, 
  ‘dateOfAssignment’ : ‘Sept 1, 2014’, ‘categoryOfAssignment’ : ‘Homework’}, 
  {‘nameOfAssignment’ : ‘Test 1’, ‘dateOfAssignment’ : ‘Sept 14, 2014’, ‘categoryOfAssignment’ :
   ‘Test’}, etc.]}
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONlib is the simplest Java API out there for generating quick and dirty JSON. It has everything you need to build up the object and convert it to text. If you need something more powerful, there's GSon and Jackson.

[Here are some samples](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/snippets.html). This example is in Groovy so it's not copy and pasteable, but it shows you how to use it:

```
def array = new JSONArray()
new File("/path/to/grades/files").eachFile { file ->
    String rawJson = file.text
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject ) JSONSerializer.toJSON( rawJson )
    array = array.element(obj)
})
println array.toString(5) //Use 5 character indentation
```

Comment: What about simple-json-1.1?  That is what I've been working with.

Comment: I think you should add more. You're saying X can do Y, but not attempting to explain how.

Comment: If I understand correctly then you are suggesting that, in order to dynamically create a JSON object that contains and sends to the Rails app all of the necessary info., I should (1) save the course, student, and assignment information to a text file first then (2) send that file as a JSON object?